# Eclipse copy header files to certain location after build

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, static-libraries, gnu-make

Is it possible to copy all your header file to a central point after a build is done? I've added this line to the Pre-Build steps in eclipse:

```
cp "${WorkspaceDirPath}/${ProjName}/*.h" "${WorkspaceDirPath}/Libs/include/";
```

The command will give this error: "recipe for target `pre-build' failed". How can I copy all the .h files to ${WorkspaceDirPath}/Libs/include/ in eclipse?

Comment: Can we see the entire 'pre-build' target with prerequisites and recipes? Might be easier to see what's happening then.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and following worked for me.

1.On Eclipse Parallel 2018-12 ( Synchronized C/C++ project) for remote projet

Instead of using environment variables, I used relative paths. To use wildcard, keep it outside the argument of function e.g

```
cp "../src/hal/pi-linux/bsp/bsp.h" "../src/hal/pi-linux/include"; 
cp "../src/hal/pi-linux/drivers/"*/*.h "../src/hal/pi-linux/include";
```

2.On Eclipse CDT for local project

If project is build locally, env variables are expanded correctly

Pre-build

```
cp "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src/pbDev}/*.h" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/include/}"; 
cp "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src/pbDev/include/sys/gcc}/*.h" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/include/}";
```

Post-build

```
cp lib${ProjName}.a "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/}";
```

Try if it works. Since question was asked quite a while ago, so answering in hope that it will be helpful for anyone still facing similar problem.